# How to resolve this object reference error in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I am receiving the following error in my web.config.

```
Parser Error Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source File: D:\Webs\behi100001\web.config    Line: 82
```

The specific error line is "type="Microsoft.Samples.SqlTableProfileProvider"

```
<providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="TableProfileProvider"
              type="Microsoft.Samples.SqlTableProfileProvider"
                connectionStringName="conBTWSqlExpress"
                table="Profile_Custom"
                applicationName="Harbor"/>
        </providers>
```

I have a file in my App_Code directory with the namespace Microsoft.Samples, with a class called SqlTableProfileProvider.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your type to:

```
type="Microsoft.Samples.SqlTableProfileProvider, <your assembly's name>"
```

where  is... well your assembly's name. I think because the the sample class is in your App_code, it is compiled into your assembly.

Comment: How do I figure out the assemblys name?

Comment: Assuming it is the filename, this is what i attempted:

      type="Microsoft.Samples.SqlTableProfileProvider, SqlTableProfileProvider"

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'SqlTableProfileProvider' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Right-click your project in the solution explorer is Visual Studio, go to Properties. The first tab is "Application", and there should be an "Assembly Name" textbox.

Comment: This is a website I'm opening remotely, via HTTP.  It is not a local project.

Assuming the URL under the solution in Solution Explorer is the project itself, I do not have a Properties menu item. The closest is a Property Pages.   Property pages has options for References, Build, Accessibility, Start Options and MSBuild Options.

This is Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: The Build page should have an output directory, which will be where the dll is for the site. The assembly name should be the dll's filename [w/o the ".dll" :-)]. I've never worked with a project the way you are unfortunately...

Comment: Unfortunately it only has a build output directory.  Thats the only thing that is specified.  There is no specific DLL file listed, which may be a side effect of opening from a remote server (shared hosting)

More than anything, I'm interested in the "why".  I'm more interested in learning how to get to the bottom of this than I am finding the actual solution.

I'm trying to dig up information on what the "add type" is looking for.  It appears the first argument in "type" is the class name, followed by the assembly.  

The referenced code is from http://tinyurl.com/2lr6vw.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what else to tell you. I'm pretty sure that the assembly needs to be the dll where the class can be found. If you have the build output directory, look in that directory to get the assembly name...

Comment: In this case, the class is not a dll, its a .cs class.  Should I try compiling it to a .dll and moving to the bin dir?

It should be accessible either way though, right?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to change

```
type="Microsoft.Samples.SqlTableProfileProvider" to  type="Microsoft.Samples.SqlTableProfileProvider, Microsoft"
```

I think you have to include the assembly name, not just the namespace.

Comment: Well, I changed the type to include ", Microsoft" and now its telling me:
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that your connection string is wrong, or your app doesn't have access to the database.

Comment: My application uses the same connection string reference in other places without error.  I definitely don't think its a database access problem.  Though I will investigate this further.